# Dealing with sources with dynamic column name in Dataflowtask

Tags: ssis, dataflowtask

I should read data from a source, which its column name changes permanently(column name is date):

[image]

I would like to write it in a table, I have such a mapping:
[image]

Of course if the column name is changed, by next run, it doesn't work anymore. Do you have any idea, how cann I specified the name of coumn dynamicly? Or how can I read the column name on air?

Is it possible to generate a new table with new column name by each running? how can I do that?

Comment: How would that be *better* than writing it to an XML file using a visual editor? That's what `dtsx` is. An XML file with the mappings which you can edit by hand, or use SSDT to do it for you.

Comment: Instead of reading directly from a table, use a view. It doesn't cost anything but allows you to change the underlying table without anyone noticing.

Comment: Do you have some examples for your ideas?

Comment: actually I don't read data from a table. I read it from a Webservice by a special component in SSIS (CData), then I think I can not use view

Answer (score 0):

You can use BiML, which dynamically generates your package based on the meta data at run time.